# Angular unit test cannot read property of subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

So im trying to create a unit test for this component and keep getting the error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. What is the reason for this and how would i properly implement a unit/integration test for this component?

**sidebar-item-component.html**

```
<a class="item"
  [ngClass]="{ active: isActive() }"
  [routerLink]="[item.path]">
  {{ item.label }}
</a>
```

**sidebar-item-component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleDef } from '../example.model';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Router,
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-item',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-item.component.html'
})
export class SidebarItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('item') item: ExampleDef;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private location: Location) {
  }

  // Checks if this current example is the selected one
  isActive(): boolean {
    return `/${this.item.path}` === this.location.path();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**spec file**

```
import { IntroComponent } from './../intro/intro.component';

import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SidebarItemComponent } from './sidebar-item.component';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NgClass, Location } from '@angular/common';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar.component';

import { ExampleDef } from '../example.model';



class RouterStub {

}

class ActivatedRouteStub {

}

class LocationStub {


}

class IntroComponentStub {

}

describe('sidebarItem component', () => {
  let component: SidebarItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidebarItemComponent>;
  let router : Router;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;
  let location: Location;




  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
      declarations: [ SidebarItemComponent],
      providers: [ {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub},
        {provide: Location, useClass: LocationStub},
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRouteStub},
        {provide: IntroComponent, useClass: IntroComponentStub}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidebarItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

fit('should link to the item path', () => {


    component.item.path = '/home';
    component.item.label = 'Intro';

    component.isActive();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.item'))
    let el: HTMLElement = de.nativeElement;
      expect(el.innerText).toContain('intro');
    });


});
```